# Connecting from IOS to ASP.Net Webservce

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, web-services, ios5

I am writing an IPad App that needs to connect to a webservice that returns and integer like this:

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">0</int>
```

My code looks like this

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:verficationURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}

-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [self.responseData appendData:data];



}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSLog(@"array: %s", result);

}
```

The connection does finish loading, but I am unable to get the value 0 out of the result. What is the right way to do this. Thank You

Comment: which parser u used for paring the XML?

Comment: @Girish As you can see I haven't yet tried using an XML Parser. Do we need to use an XML Parser in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you get the result, so  will respond only regarding the parsing.

I'm usually using [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) for easy xml parsing. There are also other third-party libraries that you can use, or use `NSXMLParsing` directly, however, you'll need to write a little more code for that.

Using it, the code for parsing would look like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:self.responseData error:&error];
NSNumber *result = [dict valueForKey:@"int"];
if(error||!result){
    // handle error (either the result is not xml format, or the xml doesn't contain a 'int' key)
}
else {
    // handle result
}
```

I haven't tested this exact code, but it should be mostly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please create REST based Web Services as it becomes very easy to interact with the DB and move on to JSON.